# Passing command line arguments to a flutter app

Tags: flutter

Is [package:args](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/args) ArgParser compatible with flutter apps? I see on Github that it is used several times in some [Flutter tools](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/df675f45ee408389782fd404849475979c125c3a/packages/flutter_tools/bin/fuchsia_builder.dart#L51), but I'm not sure it's used in any of the sample apps.

If it is not compatible, is there another way to pass configuration options to my app at compile time as part of its build rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`package:args` operates on `List<String>`, which can come from anywhere. For example, I've used it in a browser app, in which the arguments came from Chrome's JS console. If you are OK with using the [HostMessages](https://flutter.io/platform-services/) API, then the following might work for you:

On Android, turn [Intent.getExtras](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras()) into `List<String>` and pass it to `package:args`. Similarly, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272670/is-there-a-way-to-pass-command-line-options-to-my-ios-app-from-xcode) may help on the iOS side.