# Mac Catalyst: Determine App's Command Line Arguments

Tags: ios, swift, macos, mac-catalyst

Is there a way within a Mac Catalyst app to access the arguments passed along to an application launched through the command line?

Thinking it would be passed through to `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {` however, it doest not appear there.

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272670/is-there-a-way-to-pass-command-line-options-to-my-ios-app-from-xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Apple’s documentation `ProcessInfo` is available on Catalyst 13, so this should give you what you need:

```swift
import Foundation

let args = ProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments
```

The type of `args` is `[String]`.